# alternative to csplit - splitting after the pattern

Tags: csplit

I want to split a file after a delimiter, not before the delimiter, which is what csplit does. I can't find anything anywhere! (Also, why would there be a tool that specifically splits before a pattern, but not one that splits after it?)

File:
a
b
c
d

split at c

output:
file1:
a
b
c

file 2
d

Comment: _"I can't find anything anywhere!"_ Where exactly are you searching ? `csplit`, like all tools, has manual page. That's the first place to search - usually, the man page contains the answer...

Comment: It does not, it only shows how to split before a pattern... @don_crissti

Comment: What's your `csplit` version ?

Comment: 8.25 @don_crissti

Comment: If that's from `coreutils` then your man page contains the answer. How can you even say _"It does not, it only shows how to split before a pattern"_ ???

Comment: also, post a testable input content and expected splitted fragments

Comment: because the default behaviour is to split before and there is not option to change this.

Comment: The option is explained in the manual, if you bother reading it.

Comment: There are only options for `up to, but NOT including` the pattern. unless I am blind, there is no option for including it.

Comment: yeah, it's `/REGEXP/[OFFSET]` and if you read further it says `A line OFFSET is a required '+' or '-' followed by a positive integer.`

Comment: just `csplit file.txt /c/+1` - that's all

Comment: oh ok... I misunderstood that line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `/REGEXP/[OFFSET]`. So given

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
```

then

```
$ csplit file '/^c/+1'
6
2
```

gives

```
$ head xx*
==> xx00 <==
a
b
c

==> xx01 <==
d
```